# How to manage expansion for this case?

Tags: expansion

My objective is to automatically compile parameterized template from within a main input file. For each compilation, a unique jobname and parameter are passed to the compiler. The problem is, passing parameter requires me to manage both expansion and unexpansion in the proper order.

Consider the important part of MWE,

```
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\outputfilename\space "\def\name{\target} \input{template}"}
```

The `\target` must be expanded while `\def\name` must be unexpanded.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello \name
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}
\foreach \outputfilename/\target in {a/Andy,b/Bill,c/Charlie}{\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\outputfilename\space "\def\name{\target} \input{template}"}}
\begin{document}
The files we created automatically are:

\foreach \outputfilename in {a,b,c}{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=2]{\outputfilename}}\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

I have not learnt the token expansion so this case seems very disturbing in my daily usage of TeX.  How to manage these expansions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\write` operation performs expansion, which is similar to `\edef`. As such, you need `\noexpand` to protect any tokens that need to be 'left alone'. You have:

- `\outputfilename`
- `\target`
- `\space`

to be expanded and

- `\def`
- `\name`
- `\input`

to be left alone. Of those, `\def` is a non-expandable primitive in any case, so all you need is two `\noexpand`s:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello \name
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}
\foreach \outputfilename/\target in {a/Andy,b/Bill,c/Charlie}
  {\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\outputfilename\space
    "\def\noexpand\name{\target} \noexpand\input{template}"}}
\begin{document}
The files we created automatically are:

\foreach \outputfilename in {a,b,c}{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=2]{\outputfilename}}\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is due to `\foreach`, otherwise a single `\noexpand` wouldn't work, because `\write` expands its argument.

Comment: @egreg Hmm, probably you are right. I'll edit

Comment: I didn't go deeply into `pgffor.code.tex`, but if I do `\foreach\i in {a,b,c}{\show\i}` the first answer is `> \i=macro:`, which proves that `\i` is not expanded.

Answer (score 3):

```
\foreach \outputfilename/\target in {a/Andy,b/Bill,c/Charlie}{%
  \immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\outputfilename\space 
     "\def \string\name {\target} \string\input{template}"}}
```